# Looking for clarification on the behavior of Reflection.Emit when used with a lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, cil, reflection.emit

Specifically, I am attempting to create a method that takes in a lambda expression and then spins that expression off as the main method of a temporary console application at run time in order to allow for spinning off small sections of code as a separate process at run-time so I can better isolate the memory behavior (I did look into application domains but ran into other problems there due to certain limitations for my use case). Sort of a really limited fork.

This is relatively straightforward if it can be assumed that the lambda expression contains only local variables, but I am struggling with figuring out just how much I'll have to do (and how the best way to go about it is) if the expression also makes use of non-local variables (that is, a variable that exists within the enclosing scope, as per the comment below. I couldn't think of a better way at the time to phrase "a variable that is not within the local scope but is accessible").

To my knowledge, a non-local variable means a field load instruction of some sort will be generated within the MSIL. While I can potentially make a copy of the required objects/fields in the secondary application, if I try to take the MSIL of the lambda expression as-is via MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray(), then the generated code (I believe) will contain field load instructions that will be targeting metadata table entries that may (most likely will be) different than the metadata table entries for the copies of those objects/fields created in the console application via Reflection.Emit.

Further complicating this is the matter that closure, which I think/if I remember correctly means that any non-local reference within the lambda expression body will cause an object to be created that will hold the values (copies? references? I don't quite recall). I probably don't need to worry about that though, because it won't actually be a lambda expression once it is emitted as that second application in my particular use case? If I'm just getting the method body, I think I'd end up sidestepping the usual handling for closure?

Ultimately I have two questions:

A. Is there anything I'm missing in my general understanding of how this whole process will work

B. Will I have to go and just field table references in the MSIL and if so, what would be the most pragmatic way to go about this? Is there any way to get Reflection.Emit to make these adjustments for me?

Of course, I'd be happy to hear if there is some much less frustrating way to accomplish what I am attempting to do and am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to work from the `Expression` versions of the lambda and modify the code before compiling?

Comment: If the expression is not self-contained, then as a worst case you end up having to serialize *all* of your internal state (somehow) so it can be rehydrated in a brand new application. Closures are meaningless here, because whatever magic the compiler generates can't cross process boundaries, period. Given that the general problem is one you don't want to solve, I propose you don't solve it. Require that all such code *is* self-contained, and if it isn't, it must declare what it wants as parameters of simple scalar type that must be supplied explicitly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I was actually strongly considering making the user specify both the type and current value of any externally used objects/variables, but that still leaves the question of how the body of the lambda handles the references to the external variables, which from what I can tell is as table references that will likely have incorrect table indices that I need to adjust in some way to work with my encapsulation of the external data. I suppose I could make that data encapsulation an explicitly required parameter in the lambda, but I don't know how I'd enforce a lack of external refs.

Comment: Your question isn't making it entirely clear if you're getting *expression trees* (`Expression<...>`) or *actual delegates*. Either case is about equally complicated if you allow arbitrary methods to be passed in as expression trees `() => something()`, since you have no access to the actual definition of the methods that way. Patching up the generated IL to work outside the assembly entirely, while theoretically possible, seems ridonkulously complicated to me. Consider leveraging Roslyn instead and having people pass in actual source.

Comment: If you can actually *supply* the source with the executable, you can leverage [caller information](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information) to get at the source at runtime. This way, you can still have source that's developed "naturally" while also being able to access it at runtime. Effectively, just recompile the whole thing (or carefully selected parts of it, anyway). How's that for forking? This also makes it easy to allow nonlocals *and* easy to deny things like relying on internal state (by simply not making it available).

Comment: Maybe the [LambdaExpression.CompileToMethod Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728224(v=vs.110).aspx) can help you.

Comment: By "non-local" you mean an *outer variable*? That is, a local variable of the enclosing scope?

Comment: Less excitingly, consider making your unit of forking a `[Serializable]` class. Serialize it, deserialize in the child, invoke method. People can't sneak in external references that won't transfer because those will simply fail to serialize.

Comment: @NetMage That is probably a better way to go about handling changing the non-local variable references in the body than the MSIL modification, although it will still prove rather onerous to write sufficiently robust code to make the needed changes if there is no better way than combing through the expressions for references to external variables and adjusting them accordingly on an individual basis.

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, that is correct and a better way of saying it. "non-local variable" was just the best I could come up with off the top of my head. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Regarding the caller information, I don't think that would be a good approach in this case since I actually want an extremely parsed down and minimalist secondary process rather than an outright cloned one. Unless I misunderstood what you were suggesting there. The Serialization option is probably my best bet, though I was hoping to avoid any explicit interaction between the two processes past the initial spawning of the secondary process. I suppose if I'm already spawning a temporary executable, then a temporary serialized object isn't a big deal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing local variables outside an anonymous method/lambda expression creates a closure object holding the variables. Assuming you pass the lambda as a delegate, the *Target* property will contain the outside state of the delegate (something like *DisplayClass*). Unless you modify the CIL of the method, you won't get real-time communication via this class from the remote process, but you can simply serialize it and pass it to the remote process. Of course, if the delegate depends on static fields, you are left with analyzing the method to find them and serialize them (using *System.Linq.Expressions* will be helpful).

Now, if the remote process references the main assembly, it will find the *DisplayClass* there, but if not, you will have to serialize even its type and build it on the other side, hooking it with the method using *AppDomain.TypeResolve*. Then you can deserialize the object with the created type.